# How can I customize a back button to update the controller it leads to?

Tags: swift, xcode

Currently, due to the way my controllers flow into each other on the storyboard, I have one controller that doesn't immediately update with the back button unless I go to the original navigation/entry point. In other words, the controllers are set up as:

A (entrypoint) -> B -> C

If I do something in C that updates B, and I hit the back button in C, B doesn't automatically update. Is there a simple way to do this in Swift 5.1? Thanks!

Comment: Based on the answer/comments are you asking how to go from A >> B >> C back to A on a condition? Or are you asking something else? (Including virtually anything - that without code makes things hard - like *updating* B from C while going back to A?) And yes, that last question should indicate how vague your question is.

Comment: Second comment - can you be more specific? Some we can reproduce? ZTypically it goes A to B to C and vice-versa. Like in push/pop. What **exactly** are you trying to do?

Comment: “If I do something in C that updates B, and I hit the back button in C, B doesn't automatically update” Why doesn’t it? Explain or provide a reproducible case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not particularly related to Swift 5.1.

A long time ago the property [presentingViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621430-presentingviewcontroller) was introduced to get the reference to the *presenting view controller*.

Pressing the back button dismisses the actual view controller and `viewWillDisappear` / `viewDidDisappear` is called.

Add a logic to indicate there are changes and update B – which is represented by `presentingViewController` – in `viewWillDisappear` / `viewDidDisappear`.

Comment: This is far from ideal. C should update some data model or post some notification or call a delegate. B should respond and update itself. C should not update B directly.

Comment: @rmaddy What is the difference between a custom delegate reference to B and `presentingViewController`? Of course C is supposed to call a method in B in the same way protocol/delegate does.

Comment: Thanks, will I place `presentingViewController` into the coding of B or C?

Comment: @vadian They are completely different. If you directly access `presentingViewController` then you only get `UIViewController`. So then you end up casting to `B` and calling a specific method on `B`. That's a poor design due to tight coupling. By having an actual delegate in C, C doesn't care who the delegate is. C doesn't need to know anything other than to call a method of the delegate. C can be called by things other than B if you use a delegate. Or anything can be the C's delegate, not just B.

Comment: @rmaddy What's wrong with the type cast? It's the same as (forced) casting cells in `cellForRow`. The type of `presentingViewController` is clearly B as the *back button* implies a (fixed) navigation controller.

Comment: @vadian You are missing my point. The problem is the tight coupling and assumptions that must be made. The cast is far from the heart of the issue.